# oracle sql regex to extract words ending with a suffix (.sh .py etc)

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Can someone help with Oracle regex to extract words ending with `.sql`, `.sh` or `.py` in a string. For example:

```
sh /path/myscript.sh arg1 arg2
```

I am looking for a way to extract `myscript.sh`, using SQL.

Comment: "word" and "suffix" are not well defined terms. Are you looking to extract substrings consisting of letters, a period, and more letters (at least one letter on each side of the period)? What if there are digits - should those be considered too (so, "letters or digits"?) What if there is more than one such in the input? Also: must the suffix be `sql`, `sh` or `py`, or ANY suffix?

Answer (score 1):

Making lots of assumptions (see for example my question to you below the original post), perhaps all you need is

```
select regexp_substr( your_input, '[[:alpha:]]+\.[[:alpha:]]+')
from   your_table   -- or from wherever
```

Note that the period is escaped so it stands for a literal period. The rest should be self-explanatory.